# Combine onTouch onClick and onLongClick listeners

Tags: android, listener, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with items inside, I would like to distinguish between swipe (I am moving the element horizontaly making some action and setting it back to its original place) singleTouch and longClick, what is the best Practice of achieving it?
I seen a lot of implementations here, but none that work\super messy(and also dont work properly), if i implement custom gestureDetector and switchcase inside it works but it takes the phone about a second to react, if i implement onTouch in only catches onTouch, if I dont the onClick and onLong work but not the swipe

currently only the swipe works:

```
item.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 logd("TAG","2");

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

item.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    logd("TAG","1");
});

item.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
    logd("TAG","2");
});
```

any advice would be appreciated,
Thanks